# How to write a good application?

Tags: style

I recently wrote an application to get into a different program for high school. Now I feel like I could have done better with being more formal and get my message across that this program is suitable for me.

How would you go about writing a good application that is formal and convincing? Who would you direct the application for?

Any advice on writing a good application?

Comment: This is sort of primarily-opinion based.

Comment: @iiRosie1 I think contrary. I am asking for advice, and the help center does not state anything wrong about doing so.

Comment: Yes, I agree but people may have different opinions on what a "good application" is.

Comment: @Sweet_Cherry can you be more specific?  Not so specific that it makes the question into one only useful to you, but enough to give us context.  Is this a high school program? college program? work program? something else?  What is the writing portion?  Are you writing a personal essay, or perhaps a discussion of your previous work experience?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be a better fit on Workplace.SE (or Academia.SE, if it's an academic job/programme application). There is much more relevant expertise on those sites!

Comment: There is so much information about this on the web, that all you have to do is google it. Job and other applications have a specific format and structure. Explanations on this are in abundance.

Comment: @user57423 The fact that a question might also be on topic on another SE does not by itself make it off topic here. Nor does the fact that "there's information about this on the web". In fact, if there's information about this on the web, you can use this information to write an informative answer.

Comment: @Galastel First, the main reason why I want to encourage the OP to ask their question on the other mentioned SE sites is that they will get better answers there, which is clearly stated as the reason in my vote comment. Second, my recommendation to search for the easily accessible answers on the wide web instead of wasting time waiting for a low quality answer here is not part of my close vote comment and I don't understand why you react to it as if it were.

Comment: I didn't VTC at first, I just posted my comment asking for more information.  I think the question *can* be a good one.  But the OP hasn't edited it or responded, so I'll VTC now.  If the OP edits later, I'll consider reopening.

Comment: If you want the question migrated to [workplace.se], you can flag the question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: @Cyn OP edited question.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question as now that it has been edited, I don't think it's suitable for Workplace SE.

Comment: Direct the application at the person in charge of the application process. The rest of the question is still a better fit for the other sites mentioned in my previous comments, so I vote to keep closed.

Comment: This question would be closed on The Workplace because it's about school, not job, applications.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I agree. They asked me to edit the question to make it more clear so I added the school part.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically selling oneself.
So you have to show the advantages of your application (learnt skills, professional experiences, hobbies that are related to writing...)
You should create some kind of funnel, that shows that you are the perfect match for this job by tailoring your text around this specific job offer (showing that you took time to read about the job offer and the company. Sometimes there is informations about the company's culture so you can also comment around that).

And express your motivation and enthusiasm !